# OSX doesn't boot, keys out of order, rebuild catalog b-tree

Tags: macos, ssd, macbook-pro, fsck

I have a MacBook Pro 2011 with SSD drive. I have installed an update from app store, and my computer won't boot. In single mode I see errors:

```
Checking catalog 
Keys out of order
.....
.... 
Missing thread record
Invalid sibling link
Rebuilding catalog b-tree
Create new btree returned -34
Disk full error
The volume could not be repaired
```

What should I do?

**Update**:

- The SSD is not full it is only 79% full.
- The restore from the Time Machine backup did not help.
- SSD is not native and was operating without any trouble for the last year.

Comment: @alljamin yes, disk utility didn't show me any errors. But one strange thing - I can't mount partition and can't see the state of disk using disk utility.

Comment: @alljamin yes, correct. Disk is full on 79℅. When I'm in single mode type a command fsck -fy I see the same error.

Comment: @alljamin yes, but copy is not urgent. And think it is not solve this problem, maybe the SSD is corrupted after an update.

Comment: Yesterday I tried to restore from backup, left for the night, but it didn't help.

Comment: What version of OS X were you running?

Comment: @alljamin 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how you can proceed with this situation:

- Restore from a Time Machine Backup
- Start OS X recovery over the internet (you must be connected to the network) by holding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during the boot

You have not mentioned in your question was the SSD initially installed on your machine or you replaced the HDD with SSD on your own ([Apple custom builds](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp645?locale=en_US) where you can choose what type of drive you want to have). I can only assume that there could be an incompatibility issue with non original SSD.

If nothing helps then I would try replacing SSD and running "Restore from a Time Machine Backup".

Comment: SSD is not original of course, because MacBook pro 2011 ) but I've bought it 1 year ago and everything was okay.

Comment: Have you tried OS recovery over the internet?

Comment: not yet. I'll try

Comment: I tried to boot into single mode and fsck show me another error after restore from backup. Invalid structure node, also disk utility show error, which   can't be fixed

Comment: I did it !!!! After restore from backup I type command fsck_hfs -rf .... then use fs -yrpd  through terminal. After several minutes type reboot and Mac is booting in normal mode, but it was very slow...

Comment: Good for you! If you've found my answer helpful then accept it, if not then provide your own answer with all the steps you went through to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell which step was crucial. But I have:

- Restored from backup (which had an error)
- Reboot in recovery mode and opened Terminal
- Found the problematic volume and then used command `fsck -fy`, then I used the command `fsck_hfs -yprd`
- Reboot, which was slow and I had to wait a while for.
- I checked Disk Utility, which does not show errors anymore.